Broadcast receiver not working first time after process is started
I have a simple sms broadcast receiver registered in manifest.
Manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application ...>
    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

Receiver class:
class SmsReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION) {
            Log.i("sms", "received")
        }
    }
}

It work fine except for when a new process is created in response to a new sms - when device is rebooted or my app closed (and its process ended) first sms just triggers a new process start and only subsequent messages are processed by receiver.
Can someone explain to me this android behavior?

Please ignore my previous comments. They were just confusing. The behavior you've described is just not how Android works. If your app was spun up to deliver a message, it will be delivered to your Receiver. If that is your exact code, then I would have to say that you're either missing logs or misinterpreting observations. If there is actually other code involved, please provide a [mcve] for it. Beyond that, if you're testing on a real device, some manufacturers have additional restrictions on SMS and/or background activity that might be in play here, but we'd need to know what kind of device
